# Find two functions $f$ and $g$ which are integrable, but whose composition $f \circ g$ is not

Tags: calculus

> Find two functions $f$ and $g$ which are integrable, but whose composition $f \circ g$ is not.
>
> **Hint**: Use the fact that the function $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$ and $\frac{1}{q}$ if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms is **integrable** over $[0,1]$.

I assume we are going to have to use the $f$ given as one function here. I think we do $g(\frac{1}{p}) = \frac{1}{p}$ which means that $f \circ g = f(g(\frac{1}{p})) = f(\frac{1}{p}) = \frac{1}{p}$.

This doesn't work though since the composition is still **integrable**.

Comment: Are we talking about *Riemann* or *Lebesgue*?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Riemann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be given by
$$
g(x)=\cases{0& if $x=0$ \\1& otherwise}
$$
This would make $g\circ f$ unintegrable with your $f$, since $g\circ f$ is the indicator function of $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1]$ on $[0,1]$, which is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: How does that mean it isn't integrable?

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and continuous except at a set of measure zero. $f$ is discontinuous only at the rationals, and $g$ is discontinuous only at $0$, but $g\circ f$ is discontinuous everywhere.